# System Image Backup in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, ssd, backup

I have seen similar questons but not matching my situation. I have done a new install of Windows 10 on my M.2 SSD.

I am trying to make a system image (Windows 7 Style).  Here is my drive.
[Operating Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5q4zs.png)

But I get the following error.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I9nn.png)

Some have said do not ever change your system reserved partition. Others say it is a lie that you need 450 MB or much less 1G.

I have seen there is only 3rd party software to change your reserve partion.  Is this true?  Does anyone have any reccomendations?

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: Yes, use third-party software such as Macrium Reflect Free, and make a complete *disk image*, rather than just the system files (i.e., Windows style). This enables restoration of the *whole* disk should you wish to use another HDD, or if an issue develops in another partition.

Comment: That is a great plan.  But I was hoping to make a way to automatically back up every month or so..  I was able to set up a restore point, but Windows 10 doesnt seem to want to be imaged!

Comment: Most third- party tools, including previously-mentioned Reflect, can schedule images.

Comment: Use Acronis True Image to make a reliable system-independent image that can be even applied to another PC. Just create a bootable media and start Acronis from there. Image file can be stored anywhere, including external drive or FTP/SMB server in your network. See more at https://superuser.com/questions/1611912/install-windows-on-usb-from-existing-windows-installation/1611958#1611958

Comment: Thank you all!  I will give both a try...